# DataTrigger / Style quick in XAML

Tags: wpf, data-binding, xaml, datatrigger

I have an Ellipse defined as so

```
<Ellipse Stroke="#FF474747" Style="{StaticResource SelectedTemplate}" Fill="{StaticResource RedGradient}" />
```

I also have two styles setup like so

```
<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="RedGradient" GradientOrigin="1,1">
    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>

<RadialGradientBrush x:Key="GreenGradient" GradientOrigin="1,1">
    <GradientStop Color="White"/>
    <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
</RadialGradientBrush>
```

Now, when the Ellipse is first drawn it is Red as per the RedGradientBrush.  I want to make the ellipse green when a binded value (Selected) is true so I added a Style to do this

```
<Style x:Key="SelectedTemplate" TargetType="Ellipse">
    <Style.Triggers>
        <DataTrigger Value="True" Binding="{Binding Selected}">
            <Setter Property="Stroke" Value="White" />
            <Setter Property="StrokeThickness" Value="5" />
            <Setter Property="Fill" Value="{StaticResource GreenGradient}" />
        </DataTrigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
```

Now, when Selected is True ONLY the StrokeThickness changes, nothing else? Can anyone help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently XAML inline styles override any you set. This is why only the StrokeThickness was being changed as it wasn't set inline.